# Can we open Windows Explorer with custom location with HTML5 File Api?

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

By using the below line it opens the location set by Windows Explorer. But can we open some custom location like **c:\images....**  for every user who clicks on browse button etc. by using **HTML5 FileApi**.

```html
<input type="file" id="file" name="fileslist[]" multiple
 onchange="handleFileSelected()" />
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible due to security reasons, and also due to the fact, that different operating systems has different file systems (in windows we have disks, like `c:\` or `d:\`, in unix-like systems we have partitions, like `/Users`)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot control the default location.

From HTMLHelp.com :

> The file input type creates a field through which users can upload
>   files from their local computer or network. The VALUE attribute
>   specifies the name of the initial file, but it is typically ignored by
>   browsers as a security precaution. Therefore, setting an initial value
>   is not supported.